# Как получить размер установленных приложений в Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Как получить размер установленных приложений в Android.
Получаю список установленных приложений через packageManager таким образом:

```
val packList = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
    for (i in packList.indices) {
        val mapApps = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
        val packInfo = packList[i]
        if (packInfo.applicationInfo.flags and ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM == 0) {
            var appName: String = packInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString()
            val appPackageName: String = packInfo.packageName.toString()
        }
    }
```

Список получаю, основную информацию прочитать могу, но как получить размер приложений?

Comment: Сам не пробовал: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22861508/5479247